# Is it possible to authenticate the user for applications on multiple domains or IP addresses with CAS server?

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas, jasig

My environment is Spring4, and using Spring-security also.

For example, there are two servers contain the same type Java applications, powered by Jetty application server. But, they don't share JSESSIONID or any session.

- serverA: IP address 192.168.1.1

  - so, we can access the app with http://192.168.1.1/app
- serverB: IP address 192.168.1.2

  - so, we can access the app with http://192.168.1.2/app

**Question**

1. If we had a CAS server on 192.168.1.3 and also an user once logged in serverA app with CAS server, **is it possible to login serverB app without inputting id/pass by the user ?**
2. Would you please suggest simply the architecture ?

**EDIT**

- I tested this environment with Spring4 + Spring-security + Spring-cas according to the document, [21. CAS Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/cas.html)
- However, the session cookie provider is **Spring** instead of **CAS**, therefore sessions were created for each servers' IP addresses. If we had serverA's session after logged-in that, it's impossible to obtain serverB's session. I failed to reduce login attempts. I mean anyway it's necessary to input ID/Pass to login serverA & serverB each other.
- After it took a long time, I realized my real requirement that it's possible to login multiple resources ( over server resources ) with one-time login attempt. However, I think it's extended meaning of "single-sign on"...

**in passing**

- Spring-session project provides the architecture to share sessions for multiple resources. Spring-session stores their sessions on Redis back-end.
- However, it's also difficult to use Spring-session, because it requires **domains** like **a.example.com** or **b.example.com** instead of IP addresses.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? When both applications point to 192.168.1.3 as CAS server, single sign on should just work.

Comment: @JohannesMüller I assumed if I introduced CAS into this environment, I could reduce login attempts. But, it's not. This is the problem. It means, "an user once logged in serverA app with CAS server, after that  when the user will try to login serverB , he/she will be required by id/pass inputting by CAS server again ( for this environment)"

Comment: Still not sure about your trouble... serverA and serverB don't need to share a session for CAS to work. Once you're logged into serverA trough CAS, this creates a session on the CAS server. When serverB asks CAS if a user is logged in, the CAS server should not ask for authentication because there is an existing session.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to authenticate the user for applications on multiple domains or IP addresses with CAS server?

Of course yes! This is what CAS exactly do for us! When a user authenticated on CAS server, he will get a `TGT` (Ticket Granting Ticket) that will store in his browser's cookie. `TGT` means that user is authenticated and never needs to authenticate again(until logout or session expires). With a `TGT` user can go to any service in any IP or domain that is integrated with CAS and get a `ST` (Service Ticket) for individual services. So next time he will call the service with special `ST` so he does not need to contact CAS again.
For more information visit [CAS Architecture](https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/planning/Architecture.html).